# Angular smart-tables Pagination skipping

Tags: angularjs, ajax, pagination

EDIT FIXED: There's an unrelated note on using this module to load data over ajax and have sort, filter and pagination work. It requires extra steps than 99.9% of the examples out there that use an array of objects. And is even worse if you've got it working like this already, as you assume that smart tables takes care of everything. It doesn't.

Original question:

Can someone help me figure out why the table is skipping on pagination page 2 and 4. I've created a plunker and used a ton of comments, if you watch in console it'll show the flow up data coming in and being filtered out. Sort and search work, the 'filtered' array has the data in it, I can find the data on pages 2 and 4 by searching and even sorting, but not by clicking on pages 2 or 4.

http://plnkr.co/edit/LVDvjjO6NGGjlBBQEIed?p=preview

Here's the factory without the comment craziness:

```
app.factory('mongodbApi', function($http, $q, $filter) {

    // CAN ADD OTHER APIs HERE TO TEST OUTSIDE OF
    // EXPRESS.JS

    // GET
    var getRecords = function(url, start, number, params) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http.get(url)
            .success(function(res) {
                var filtered = params.search.predicateObject ? $filter('filter')(res, params.search.predicateObject) : res;

                if (params.sort.predicate) {
                    filtered = $filter('orderBy')(filtered, params.sort.predicate, params.sort.reverse);
                }
                result = filtered.slice(start, start + number)
                    // why is this skipping 5 items? 
                defer.resolve({
                    data: result,
                    numberOfPages: Math.ceil(res.length / number)
                });
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                defer.reject(err);
            });

        return defer.promise;
    };

    return {
        getRecords: getRecords,
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[The OP wrote in an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que):

> I fixed it by setting 'st-items-by-page="5"' on the st-pagination div. Read on though as It's a bit more complicated than that.
>
> So my index 'start' variable was being incremented by 10 when I click on page 2 and set to 20 when I click on page 3. According to the source defaults:
>
> ```
> pagination: {
>   template: 'template/smart-table/pagination.html',
>   itemsByPage: 10,
>   displayedPages: 5
> }
> ```
>
> I thought that by setting my start as 0 and my tableState.pagination.number to 5 that smart-tables would know I wanted 5 items per page and it does, but it doesn't increase the start index value accordingly. You actually have to balance the values. This should probably be updated in the docs. It didn't take forever to figure out but I've been messing with this module for a few weeks now.
>
> ---
>
> NOTE ABOUT AJAX CALLS
>
> For anyone interested in using ajax, you have to use the st-pipe directive on your table. This will be called when you do anything, sort, filter or change page and it will get the most current data from the server. Per the docs under the ajax/pipe section you can see how to do 99% of it. Just be aware that you're going to be setting up a $filter on tableState.search and tableState.sort, and passing resulting slice of this object back from your ajax promise. And like I wrote up here you have to balance the tableState values.
>
> AGAIN, itemByPage is the INDEX on the array you're returning to your table i.e. WHERE to start showing, tableState.pagination.number are the line items that will be displayed per page i.e. HOW MUCH to show.
>
> Probably plain as day for some out there. And experienced programmer especially in Angular will probably laugh it off. I could care less to be honest I 'learned' Angular 2 months ago. Have fun and happy ajaxing, use the plunker and look at the console.
>
> Hope that helps.